# Laplace-Beltrami operator

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, reference-works

I'm interesting in the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a sphere, more precisely its spectral properties including the spectral function, etc. So if someone can give me  some references that treats this subject profoundly I'll be grateful ! Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you don't indicate that you're cross-posting, it can lead to duplicated effort as people on both sites try to answer your question. It's better to post on one site and then maybe (if it seems appropriate) post on the other site after a day or two if you haven't gotten any responses, linking to your original post.